# How to make the connection string of an Windows form application in C#.net,Computer independent?

Tags: c#

As I transfer my Windows form application in C#.net from one computer to another, I have to change the connection string every time as the location of the Database file has changed.

How can I can I prevent this,so that I don't have to change the connection string again and again?

Comment: Put the database file in a consistent location?

Comment: Can you **show us** such a connection string as a sample?? What database are we talking about here??

Comment: Where are you storing your connection string now? Surely you don't mean that you have to *recompile* the application to put it on another machine?

Comment: Depending on the kind of database you are connecting to, connection strings should be machine independent from the get-go. Can you post a sample connection string so we can see how it is machine dependent and see what kind of database you are connecting to?

Comment: Also, you really should not double post the same question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4238339/how-to-make-the-connection-string-of-an-application-in-c-net-computer-independen

Comment: You should probably update the question with the connection string examples, rather than add the details to each answer. Reading the code within your comments isn't easy.

Comment: @Tom007 have any of the answers helped, or are you still having problems?

Answer (score 2):

If the service you need to connect is always running on the local machine, you might use the `localhost` as the server name...

By the way `localhost` is mapped to the ip 127.0.0.1 in the hosts file.

Answer (score 0):

Have your DB file in the same location of your application exe and then you can use

```
Application.StartupPath()
```

to get the path.

*I am assuming that this is a Windows Forms Application.

Comment: string c = Application.StartupPath; SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"DataSource=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename='" + c + "'\\abcd.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True");                                                                                                                         ArgumentException was unhandled.

Comment: Original path of the Database :-                                  Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=E:\visual2008\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\bin\Debug\abcd.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True

Answer (score 0):

It's tricky to tell without an example of the type of connection string you're using (or which database you're accessing) but can't you use a relative path and assume that the database is somewhere relative to your app?

If you set your connection sting up like this...

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ConsoleApplication1.Properties.Settings.Database1ConnectionString"
        connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

... then |DataDirectory| will by default resolve to the application's folder. You can, however, change DataDirectory by calling the AppDomain.SetData method. See the following for how to change it...

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetdataproviders/thread/805bfd29-d864-4400-b353-bea13167f046

I've shown how you'd set the connection string in config, but the same holds true if you're setting it in code. If you are building a connection string in code, then may I suggest you look at using a connection string builder...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254947.aspx

I am, of course, assuming a file path in your connection string, but if it's a database then won't localhost also work?

Comment: SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Documents and Settings\Darshan\My Documents\abc.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True");

Answer (score 0):

How has the location of the database changed? Is it not in a central location that all computers/users can access?

If not, you could store the connection information in settings and create a form that allows you to update those as needed. The form could be launched as part of the installer or on first run of the application.

A little more information about what you're doing would be helpful in presenting a real solution.

Comment: SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Documents and Settings\Darshan\My Documents\abc.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True");